# Multiple content types from Views module, not old nodes from one of them

Tags: views, nodes, datetime

I use the famous Views module to show nodes of different content types. One of these content types has a field called "final date". If a node has an old date, smaller than today's date, I want it to disappear from the start page so it's always up to date. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To filter out content that has a "final date" that is in the past, you can set up a filter as follows on the view for this content type.

Filter on "final date" "is greater than or equal to" an offset date of "+0 minutes".

Screenshot below shows the final setting (in the screenshot example I used the "Post date" as the date field to filter on, but in your case it should be "Final date.")

[image]

Alternately, you could look at the [Scheduler module](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) and instead of using a "Final date" field, schedule these nodes to unpublish at a certain date. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have this view return a set limit of records and sort DESC on the `final date` field?

Comment: Sure! But how should I proceed?